# Is sourcing a quote within Arqade's area of expertise?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Yesterday, I asked a question pertaining to the origin of a quote from MGS2.  The question can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181659/is-there-an-original-source-for-this-quote-from-mgs2?noredirect=1#) (Edit: The question has been removed since it is off-topic).  Now the reason it is downvoted is due to some questionable cross-site posting on my part, which is my bad, but not the reason I'm asking this Meta question.

In the comments, it was mentioned that "sourcing is not really in our (Arqade's) area of expertise".  I accept this, but if it really isn't, shouldn't there be an area in the FAQ that includes this as being outside our area of expertise?

I would think it'd be covered under Game Identification, but wouldn't the quote count as an audiovisual artifact?  Or is a quote of text not enough?  And if not from that rule, is there another rule that states that this sort of question isn't covered by Arqade?

Related to, but not a duplicate, of [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9876/how-to-address-cross-network-duplicate-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, the question isn't closed, and there are no close votes. But the question isn't really about the game. You're basically asking "What is the original source of this quote?" It might be Metal Gear Solid 2, and it might be another game, and it might be somewhere else entirely. Gamers might be more likely to know because the quote appeared in the game, and especially so if that was in fact the source, but the fact remains that the question only tangentially relates to the game itself.

Comment: Having had some time to think about it, maybe it would be better to ask if Otakon and Meiling are just making up some of these 'quotes'?  That would cover the real question I'm trying to address, and change focus from being about the quote to about the games themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You're still asking if the lines from the game first appeared in that game or somewhere else. And another issue is that it's hard to prove a negative (that the quotes didn't come from somewhere else).

Comment: Both true...and I can't really think of a better way to phrase it either.  And I don't think that ELU would be able to help, since I know this quote *is* in MGS2, and possibly only in that game.

Comment: If you Google the quote, all of the links reference back to MGS2. And I don't think you'll get a better answer than that.

Comment: True, and it's also a full line of text, not just a word or two that might've been misappropriated.